# android aosp unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

I am trying to build the AOSP automotive car emulator, I am receiving the following error

```
============================================
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=9
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_car_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=darwin
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Darwin-18.6.0-x86_64-10.14.5
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=PD2A.190115.032
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
ninja: no work to do.
[1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja 
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/Android.bp:1:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"
error: hardware/nxp/nfc/extns/intf/nxpnfc/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"
error: hardware/nxp/nfc/extns/intf/nxpnfc/1.0/Android.bp:8:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/schedulerservice/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/vr/composer/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: hardware/nxp/secure_element/extns/intf/nxpese/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"
error: hardware/nxp/secure_element/extns/intf/nxpese/1.0/Android.bp:8:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/sensorservice/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: hardware/google/interfaces/Android.bp:4:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"
error: hardware/interfaces/Android.bp:1:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
14:09:59 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (17 seconds) ####
```

I have am executing the command `make -j32` after which I am receiving this error. I have created a separate disk image as mentioned in the documentation to build the environment for aosp. I am using the Mac Mojave OS.

Comment: Please check my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/72043748/10183099

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem building AOSP, in my case for the Pixel 2 XL with build number `PQ3A.190801.002`.

I started from scratch, doing the same as before, but more carefully this time. It worked. I didn't take the time to confirm what exactly went wrong, but I strongly suspect I accidentally downloaded the wrong proprietary drivers from [here](https://developers.google.com/android/drivers). Since this is also not a common issue at all, it might be the same cause for you