# AOSP build error: unrecognized module type "hidl_package_root"

Tags: linux, android-source, android-soong

I'm keep getting that error in soong, while trying to build aosp.

When I type `make`, this is the output:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=R
PLATFORM_VERSION=R
TARGET_PRODUCT=sdk_phone_x86_64
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=eng
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_ARCH=x86_64
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=x86
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=x86_64
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_2ND_ARCH=x86
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.15.0-1079-oem-x86_64-Ubuntu-19.10
HOST_CROSS_OS=windows
HOST_CROSS_ARCH=x86
HOST_CROSS_2ND_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=AOSP.MASTER
OUT_DIR=out
============================================
[100% 1/1] out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build out/soong/build.ninja
FAILED: out/soong/build.ninja
out/soong/.bootstrap/bin/soong_build -t -l out/.module_paths/Android.bp.list -
b out/soong -n out -d out/soong/build.ninja.d -globFile out/soong/.bootstrap/b
uild-globs.ninja -o out/soong/build.ninja Android.bp
error: hardware/interfaces/Android.bp:1:1: unrecognized module type "hidl_pack
age_root"
error: hardware/google/interfaces/Android.bp:4:1: unrecognized module type "hi
dl_package_root"
error: hardware/google/interfaces/light/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized modul
e type "hidl_interface"
error: hardware/google/interfaces/light/1.1/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized modul
e type "hidl_interface"
error: hardware/google/interfaces/media/c2/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrecognized mo
dule type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/Android.bp:1:1: unrecognized module type
 "hidl_package_root"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/cameraservice/service/2.0/Android.bp:3:1
: unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/sensorservice/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unreco
gnized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/displayservice/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unrec
ognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/schedulerservice/1.0/Android.bp:3:1: unr
ecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: frameworks/hardware/interfaces/cameraservice/common/2.0/Android.bp:3:1:
 unrecognized module type "hidl_interface"
error: packages/modules/DnsResolver/Android.bp:13:1: unrecognized module type 
"aidl_interface"
error: frameworks/base/Android.bp:856:1: unrecognized module type "aidl_interf
ace"
error: frameworks/base/Android.bp:990:1: unrecognized module type "aidl_mappin
g"
19:37:38 soong bootstrap failed with: exit status 1

#### failed to build some targets (2 seconds) ####
```

I've tried it with `aosp_x86_64-eng`, `aosp_arm-eng` and `sdk_phone_x86_64_64`, but I'm keep getting the same error. I'm using ubuntu 19.10.

When I type `lunch`, it also says that:
`Warning: Cannot display lunch menu.`

Comment: This looks like your AOSP's build tooling does not match the rest of the source tree. Is there something weird with your `build/make/` or `build/soong` checkouts?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by weird ? Sorry if that's a dumb question, but I'm new to aosp.

Comment: Does the checked out branch of `build/make/` match the branch of `hardware/interfaces`? You tagged the question as `linux`, but your `Soong` log output suggest you are building under windows, which is not officially supported AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, i think I checked out the same branch.

Comment: I have SAME problem... How did you resolve your problem? Ubuntu 20.04. Twrp android 10 build. I builded twrp 9 with no problem.

Comment: I resolved my case by removing vendor directory and `repo sync` with correct tree + `export ALLOW_MISSING_DEPENDENCIES=true`

Answer (score 0):

Android 10 uses older `Android.bp` system that does not support some things newer AOSP version `Android.bp` supports.

try building your `Android.bp` with the latest AOSP once.